# C# ActiveX / IE 10 / Multiple Tabs / Get ActiveX MainWindowHandle

Tags: c#, activex

I have an ActiveX project running happily in IE10.

A situation has occured that requires me to obtain the MainWindowHandle of the tab the control is running in.

The following code returns the MainWindowHandle for IE - and not the tab the ActiveX control is running in:

```
 Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
```

If I run this code it returns more than one handle depending on how many tabs are open:

```
 Process[] IEPROCS = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
 foreach(Process Proc in IEPROCS) {

     //output code
     Proc.MainWindowHandle.ToString();

 }
```

So how do I determine the handle of the tab the ActiveX is running in?

For "Legacy" purposes I have to do this in .NET V2 so WindowsInteroptHelper is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

- Get a Win32 HWND of the control's window: `IntPtr hWnd = this.Handle.ToPointer();`
- Use [GetParent](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getparent) to walk up the parent chain of windows, until I find a window with Win32 class name `TabWindowClass` ([GetClassName](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetClassName.html) can be used to get the name of the class).
- That would be the HWND of the wanted IE tab.